# Move 3-dot separator in Status Bar

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar

Using Excel VBA, how can I move the 3-dot separator in the status bar? I want to move it a little to the right of the circled-plus "add sheet" button.

The sheet name will always be the same, so, if necessary, hardcoding a position relative to the left edge of the window isn't a problem.

[image: Excel status bar 3-dot separator]

Found out how to do this based on answer:

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = 150

ActiveWindow.TabRatio = pos / ActiveWindow.Width
```

Comment: see [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-tabratio-property-excel)

Comment: @ScottCraner: wow.

Comment: @SMeaden Just recorded a macro, then did a google search on the result.

Comment: ah , of course.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Window property called `TabRatio`. It is on a scale from 0 to 1, where 0 is the far left of the status bar, and 1 being the far right of the status bar.

Here is a basic example:

```
Private Sub letTabRation()

    'WAY OF SEEING WHAT THE CURRENT RATIO IS
    Debug.Print ActiveWindow.TabRatio

    'WAY OF LETTING THE RATIO IN VBA
    ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.117

End Sub
```

Just note that there is a margin on the left side of this, you may have to play around with it in your sheet, and read what the property current is set to!